# Paypal showing error page while passing variables to sandbox environment

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to integrate paypal for one time donation save data to database and then mark paid/unpaid using Paypal IPN, I was working with below code yesterday, it was working fine and was redirecting me to sandbox page to pay and then come back.

below is my php form

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>controller/function" name="DonationForm" id="DonationForm" class="mt-20">
 <input type="number" min="1" placeholder="Amount" id="amount" name="amount" class="form-control">
---- here i have some more variables to insert in database--
</form>
```

and below is my codeigniter function

```
$UniqueIdGenrated=md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), FALSE));
$UniqueId=$UniqueIdGenrated;
$paypal_email = 'my_sandbox_bussiness_email@gmail.com';

$return_url = 'https://my_domain.com/controller/payment-successful';
$cancel_url = 'https://my_domain.com/controller/payment-cancelled';
$notify_url = 'https://my_domain.com/paypal/listener.php';

$currency_code='USD';
$item_name='Donation for a cause';
$item_number=$UniqueId;
$amount=$_POST['amount'];

$cmd='_xclick';
//$lc='UK';
//$bn='PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynow_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest';

$querystring = '';
$querystring .= "?business=".urlencode($paypal_email)."&";
$querystring .= "item_name=".urlencode($item_name)."&";
$querystring .= "amount=".urlencode($amount)."&";
$querystring .= "item_number=".urlencode($item_number)."&";
$querystring .= "currency_code=".urlencode($currency_code)."&";
$querystring .= "cmd=".urlencode($cmd)."&";

// Append paypal return addresses
$querystring .= "return=".urlencode(stripslashes($return_url))."&";
$querystring .= "cancel_return=".urlencode(stripslashes($cancel_url))."&";
$querystring .= "notify_url=".urlencode($notify_url);
header('location:https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'.$querystring);
exit();
```

However today when I started testing again, paypal says "Things don't appear to be working at the moment. Please try again later."

[image: Here is the sandbox error screenshot]

I tried keeping below as header, live paypal

```
header('location:https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'.$querystring);
```

then it has taken me properly on paypal payment page below is the screen shot

[image: Here is the live paypal screen shot]

Can anyone please help me, am i missing something :(

Comment: Please take some time to properly format your question. Also embed images instead of pasting the links.

Comment: Hi emix, thank you for looking, I am new to stackoverflow, when I tried to insert image, it came as link only.

Comment: Well you were supposed to use the "Insert image" tool. Anyway, always please crop the images as well as your browser/system toolbars are not relevant here.

Comment: I thought the url in address bar might help, that's why kept whole screen shot, however noted for future post, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Weird, now it's working fine with the same code and redirecting me to paypal sandbox as intended. below is the screen shot.
I guess paypal sandbox server was down or something, or might be there was some temporary glitch... don't know.
Thanks!!

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOoop.png)